# Xcode 6.4 - Unable to set constraints on Views or ... anything

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, constraints

There are many guides out there that talk about auto-layout such as: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

Now constraints don't seem to be super complicated except that when it comes to trying to set them on a UIImageView within a ViewController, With "Use Auto-Layout" ticked, I can't for the life of me set any constraints as when I click any of the three buttons used to achieve this, all the options for setting constraints is greyed out.

I'm sure this is something simple... little help?

I've found something in reference materials: "Constraint options that require multiple elements are disabled if you have only a single element selected." but in none of the guides do I have to have more than the UIImageView selected to set constraints.

Edit: added images:

[image: ContraintsGreyedOut1of2]

[image: ContraintsGreyedOut2of2]

Comment: If you click on your UIImageView in your storyboard you should be able to click one of the constraint options at the bottom of your window. You're saying you're unable to do so? Take a screenshot of what you're trying to auto-layout.

Comment: How did you wind up with an image view as the main view of a view controller? Your storyboard is malformed. You've probably also forgotten to re-connect the view controller's `view` outlet to the image view. But seriously - don't do this.

Comment: Also I notice that there's no size classes menu in the middle of the bottom of the canvas. This storyboard is hosed. Give up and start over.

Comment: add constraints to the object that you want before you link that imageview within your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you remove root view from view controller. When you add UIViewController to storyboard you can see this:

[image]

If you delete this view and add UIImageView you see this:

[image]

[image]

So add UIView as root and UIImageView as single subview of root view. And then you can play with constraints:

[image]

Answer (score 51):

In my case, Xcode 11.2 somehow set layout property of my `UIButton` `tranlates mask into constraints`. So I changed it to `automatic` from size inspector and it is fixed.

Comment: Neither "automatic" nor "translates mask into constraints" is an option for the layourt property of my UIButton in xcode 13.2

Why apple thinks its a good idea to change the user interface in *every single release* is beyond me. I've found 5 different "answers" to doing this thing in the interface, all of them outdated.

Answer (score 5):

if you move a View around (eg. move it IN then OUT a TableView) then it will mysteriously loose its ability to accept constraints. So build a new one.
XCode 11.4.1

Comment: this xcode bug is still there in Xcode 13.4.1

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't set the constraints is because your image view is not in a view, it is the base view.  In order to set constraints on a view of any kind, it must be inside another view.

Answer (score 1):

Auto layout constraints are either relationships between two objects or size constraints. You have only one object in this example, so no auto layout constraints are applicable here. Size constraints are also not applicable because this is the root view of your xib.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but you would have full set of auto layout constraints if you placed your UIImageView on the content view of this view controller instead of changing its class.

Answer (score 0):

[image: UIImageView Selected + Add New Constraints button]

All I did, clean and simple was:
- At your view, add the UIImageView
- Select your UIImageView
- Click on the "Add New Constraints" button (shown in the attached picture).

As you can see, the UIImageView is selected.

The only possible explanation is that you may have forgotten to select it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I confronted with the same situation. But in my case, I tried to insert imageview into horizontal stack view. Strangely, I could not add constraints for width and height value for imageview.
I was able add the constraints only after **deleting the current and adding a new imageview**.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I had constraint objects on the storyboard that I wanted to link to constraints on a view within my view controller and the order I linked them in is what allowed me to link them.

If I had already linked the view object to a view in the view controller, I could not add constraints to the object in the storyboard, and by not being able to do that couldn't associate those constraints to the ones on the view controller.

But if I created the constraints on the view object before I associated it to the view on the controller, then I could then link the constraints 1st and then link the view itself afterwards.